# Xpath3 expression or XSLT code to fetch all node names with particular attributes in order that they appear

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the below XML structure and I need to retrieve all node names that have attributes isAdded or isUpdated = 1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<peci:Effective_Change xmlns:peci="urn:com.workday/peci" peci:Sequence="0">
    <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
    <peci:Effective_Moment>01.11.2020</peci:Effective_Moment>
    <peci:Entry_Moment>23.11.2020</peci:Entry_Moment>
    <peci:Worker_Status>
        <peci:Status>Active</peci:Status>
        <peci:Active>1</peci:Active>
    </peci:Worker_Status>
    <peci:Position peci:isAdded="1">
        <peci:Position_ID>P0000</peci:Position_ID>
        <peci:Business_Site>
            <peci:Location_ID>US</peci:Location_ID>
        </peci:Business_Site>
        <peci:Position_End_Date peci:isAdded="1">01.11.2020</peci:Position_End_Date>
    </peci:Position>
    <peci:Position peci:isUpdated="1">
        <peci:Position_ID>P0000</peci:Position_ID>
        <peci:Business_Site>
            <peci:Location_ID>US</peci:Location_ID>
        </peci:Business_Site>
        <peci:Position_End_Date peci:isAdded="1">01.11.2020</peci:Position_End_Date>
    </peci:Position>
    <peci:Compensation peci:isUpdated="1">
        <peci:Position_ID>P0000</peci:Position_ID>
        <peci:Primary_Job>1</peci:Primary_Job>
        <peci:Business_Site>
            <peci:Country>US</peci:Country>
        </peci:Business_Site>
    </peci:Compensation>
</peci:Effective_Change>
```

The output I am looking for is a list like below

```
Positon isAdded
Positon isUpdated
Compensation isUpdated
```

Can someone help?

Comment: What have you tried? Sounds like a simple task of selecting the elements with the right predicate and then in the last step apply a function or two to get the name or concat it with the attribute.

Comment: Hi Martin.....Sorry I did not put what I tried....will put that going forward. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems very straightforward, something like:

```
/*/*[@peci:isAdded = 1 or @peci:isUpdated = 1]/(local-name() || ' ' || local-name(@*)]
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. This works. Appreciate the quick response.